# Calling javascript function with parameters from thymeleaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I need to call a javascript function from html using thymeleaf. In this particular case I have a student object and I need to pass this student object to a javascript function (edit()) for processing on button click.

Important code segments:

```
<form action="/addStudent" method="post">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>


<table>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
</tr>
<tr th:each="student : ${students}">
    <td th:text="${student.id}"></td>
    <td th:text="${student.name}"></td>

    <td>
        <button type="button" th:onclick="'edit(\'' + ${student} + '\');'">Edit</button>
    </td>
</tr></table>

<script type="text/javascript">
function edit(student)
{
    console.log("--------------------edit---------------------" + student.name);
}</script>
```

But it doesn't work as expected. It shows the following error. Can anyone help by showing how to pass student object from thymeleaf to javascript function?

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/students.html]")
>    org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/students.html]")

Comment: What do you mean not as expected? Do you get the student obj correctly inside the edit function?

Comment: @Eytan updated the original post with error message.

Comment: Check what student is in the edit function. Add debugger; at the beginning of the function. Press F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I to catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons you've to define the parameter to use as a data attribute (in the newest versions of thymeleaf). Do it in the following way:

```
th:data-student="${student}" th:onclick="edit(this.getAttribute('data-student'))"
```

Comment: This works pretty well, but only for strings. If I try to get student property name it says undefined. Can we pass the whole student object so that javascript function can access its all attributes?

Comment: @Ruchira the easiest way is probably to use JSON format in the data attribute, then retrieve it in js. Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GlauberRocha/Q6kKU/

Comment: Will try that. Thanks!